# сравнение SIFT дескрипторов особых точек (OpenCV 3)

Tags: c++, c, opencv

Буду признателен, если коллеги подскажут ссылку или исходник, где можно подсмотреть, как правильно добираться до значений вектора дескрипторов ключевых (особых) точек изображения, полученных с помощью SIFT детектора. О существовании cv::DescriptorMatcher мне известно, однако в моем случае хотелось бы получить оценку коэффициента корреляции d=(X*Y)/(||X||* ||Y||) дескрипторов X и Y. Ниже воспроизводимый проблемный код:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"

 //Проблемы в этой  функции, скачанной из Интернет, как есть. Очевидно, что если бы она работала, то ее легко переделать в нужную мне функцию вычисления коэффициента корреляции d=(X*Y)/(||X||* ||Y||).
double euclidDistance(cv::Mat& vec1, cv::Mat& vec2) {
double sum = 0.0;
int dim = vec1.cols;
for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
    sum += (vec1.at<uchar>(0, i) - vec2.at<uchar>(0, i)) * (vec1.at<uchar>(0, i) - vec2.at<uchar>(0, i));
}
return sqrt(sum);
}

//Действующий усеченный фрагмент кода, в котором вызывается проблемная функция
void _produceAnalogyPoints(cv::Mat img)
{
//Создаем стандартный SIFT детектор
cv::Ptr<cv::Feature2D> f2d = cv::xfeatures2d::SIFT::create();

//Выделяем из входного изображения все особые точки
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
f2d->detect(img, keypoints);

//Для каждой особой точки строим вектор дескрпторов
cv::Mat descriptors;
f2d->compute(img, keypoints, descriptors);

//Для каждой пары особых точек с близкими дискрипторами и удовлетовояющих некоторому дополнительнуму критерию _geometrySuitable(pt1, pt2) выполняем некую операцию
    for (int i = 0; i < keypoints.size(); i++)
    {
        cv::KeyPoint pt1 = keypoints[i];

        for (int j = i + 1; j < keypoints.size(); j++)
        {
              //Отсеиваем  особые точки, не удовлетворяющие определенному критерию 
              cv::KeyPoint pt2 = keypoints[j];

              //if (_geometrySuitable(pt1, pt2) ) - будем считать, что проверка прошла
              {
               //Расстояние между дескрипторами
               cv::Mat desc1 = descriptors.row(i);
               cv::Mat desc2 = descriptors.row(j);

               //Здесь проблема
               double d = euclidDistance(desc1, desc2);

               if (d < 0.01)
                {
                //Делаем некие полезные действия
                //........................
                }
          }
      }
   }

}
```

При выполнении этого кода в функции euclidDistance(...), скачанной из Интернет, возникает исключение "Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEFD52A06D in program.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000000022EBF0."

Это происходит в этом месте:`sum += (vec1.at<uchar>(0, i) - vec2.at<uchar>(0, i)) * (vec1.at<uchar>(0, i) - vec2.at<uchar>(0, i));` при вызове функции доступа к элементам вектора `vec1.at<uchar>(0, i)`

Собственно вопрос - как правильно выдернуть из дескриптора отдельное значение, или, как в ОpenCV - 3 рассчитать коэффициента корреляции d=(X*Y)/(||X||* ||Y||) SIFT дескрипторов X и Y?